# DB Communication in Magento1.6?

Tags: database, oracle, magento, integration, adapter

I have attached link containing DB communication in Magento. Can anybody please explain how to integrate Magento with Oracle from above diagram? What files are needed to do the same? Has anybody develop Oracle adapter for Magento?

Please guide me...

www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/RDBMS_Guide2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure,

but you shold try this way:

1. Get Zend's Adapter for Oracle
2. In magento's

```
     {root}/app/etc/local.xml
```

there are some settings to specify database and tool to connect, if i don't mistake.